# Is there a way to see the pokestops and gyms on a map?

Tags: pokemon-go

I'm on vacation on a pretty rural area and there is only 3 pokestops and a gym around me. I wonder how many pokestops and gyms are near my house in another city.

Is there a way to see pokestops and gyms in other places in a map (preferably online)?

---

There seems so be loads of websites linked. While posting your own website is allowed (as long as it answers the question properly) please keep in mind that **stating your affiliation is required** (Add something like "Disclaimer: I own this website" to the end of your answer) in order to avoid being spam flagged.

Comment: I think ingress' intel page might work, but I'd need to download ingress to my phone first- would prefer downloading when I find out if it is required or not as my phone's storage is pretty full.

Comment: There isn't currently an official map, but someone has created a community Google Map to crowd source locations. You can get the link on the /r/pokemon Subreddit [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4rmu0d/so_someone_created_a_map_where_you_can_add_gyms/).

Comment: You can always go look for a church ;)

Comment: @Nolonar living in an islamic country unfortunately :(

Comment: @ardaozkal a mosque, then?

Comment: @scenia I checked - 3 mosques near here, none has pokestops.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As I mentioned in [this article](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272867/does-pokemon-go-have-same-points-as-ingress), the portals from this game and Ingress do appear to be identical, with many portals being pokestops and mission portals being gyms. However, they do seem to have a limitation on the density of portals, so not portal has been converted.

Therefore, using the ingress intel map will provide you with your Pokémon Go map. I haven't found an official map yet, but this has served me will so far.

Or just look for any of the following, as they are typically great hubs:

- Shopping centers
- Parks
- Museums
- Churches
- City Landmarks (city hall etc)
- Historical Landmarks (statues etc)
- College Campuses
- Any other tourist-y location

Ingress portals are based upon notable looking landmarks. If you know any place that fits the categories above, it's probably a pokestop.

UPDATE:

Some pokestops have been removed from the game due to complaints, such as some in residential areas or ones around Police Stations etc. I have not checked if this change has been reflected in Ingress, but it has affected Pokémon Go.

Comment: The well in this town is literally a gym. I guess that is touristy.

Comment: @ardaozkal well if you have a city hall or park or anything "city" related, it tends to have poke stops. Unless you literally only have a gym. Then you MAYYYYY want to invest in a good car. Or just pay for pokeballs. Best of luck!

Comment: There are thankfully 3 pokestops here, one is a park, one is a statue (Might want to consider adding this to your list as it might be common) and the other is a mosque so your list seems pretty good.

Comment: @ardaozkal that was supposed to be included under museum but that didn't really make sense. I've added it as well. Thank you!

Comment: In the nearby village, there are three Ingress portals; none of them has a mission. One is a gym, an other a pokestop, and the third is NOT in Pokemon Go at all. That said, Ingress is a good starting point; they probably didn't include the third because two were enough, but I doubt they would omit an isolated portal.

Comment: "all portals being pokestops and mission portals being gyms" This is not the case. As you can see [here](http://imgur.com/gallery/Tj1Jv), there are several Ingress portals that do not have corresponding Pokestops

Comment: @SnoringFrog I should have chosen my wording more carefully, but if you read the second thread I linked, I do mention the limitations of density. "However, they do seem to have a limitation on the density of portals" Additionally, they have been removing pokestops (i'm not sure about portals since I haven't checked recently) due to complains etc. I shall update my answer to reflect this information.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an alternative. You can use the existing map from Ingress and then with an additional plugin you can see the POGO stops and gyms. Article says it all.

https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4rm9rt/faq_here_is_how_niantic_knew_about_that_local/

Comment: I'm using this right now and it works pretty well. (not accepting as answer as the other one has more content and answers in other ways (in case website goes down etc) too)

Comment: Servers for that are pretty much dead. (The IITC plugin connects to external servers)

Answer (score 1):

there are some differences to the ingress map, but people have started mapping out the points themselves on this public map, so you can go and help there if you wish c: https://www.google.com/maps/d/edit?mid=1fYglPQeuhN4VcYCa_BD53eIAlpw

Answer (score 1):

all those google maps end up sabotaged.
this is a custom map where data is stored in private database so people cannot sabotage it.

http://map.pokego.no/

enjoy

Answer (score 0):

Literally any place 'important' is a pokestop (every church, community center/park or shopping center in my area) but some of the gyms are in super random places.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at pokiego.com it looks like they only have gyms for Australia and NZ though.

Comment: @Damek If the question is asking for a website, why is an answer that gives a website a bad thing?

Comment: The site seems to be down