# Does Pokemon Go have same points as Ingress?

Tags: ingress, pokemon-go

Pokemon go and ingress are both developed by the same company. Does Pokemon Go have same points (pokestops and gyms - portals etc.) as Ingress?

Comment: related http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272750/how-are-pokestops-chosen

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Yes**

The portals from Ingress and the Pokestops and gyms from Pokémon Go are at the same locations.

However, they do seem to have a limitation on the density of portals. Common areas that had dozens of portals in a single location on Ingress have had their numbers reduced so they are more spread out. There seems to be a minimum distance between portals/centers, but I don't have an exact value.

Shout out to @sterno for mentioning and confirming the portal reduction.

Source:

I just started playing Pokémon Go (as did everyone else) but I have been playing ingress for over a month and am level 8. All of my regular portals have become Pokestops and Gyms. I have noticed that the Portals that are "Mission Portals" seem to have become Gyms. I have no yet had the chance to check some of my normal farms to see if EVERY portal has been used, but I will be checking tonight and hopefully remember to update this post :)

Comment: This is not entirely correct. The Pokemon Go locations are a subset of the Ingress ones. There is a 9 portal farm in Ingress right next to my work. In Pokemon Go, there are only 3 locations there.

Comment: My apologies. I forgot to add the distance criteria. I'll add that now.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is mostly true, but some areas of the map have been entirely left off. I'm not sure why. For example, downtown Austin has plenty of portals but nothing for Pokemon. I hope this changes. Maybe it's a glitch??

Answer (score -2):

Every gym and pokestop from Pokemon Go is a portal, however not every portal is a gym or pokestop. Both games do appear to draw on the same database of locations, though.

Comment: Please stop posting answers to old questions when you do not have anything new to add.