# Is there any way to pre-plan my adventure like in Ingress?

Tags: pokemon-go

In [ingress](/questions/tagged/ingress), there is an [Intel Map](http://ingress.com/intel/) that allows you to see what portals/links/fields are where and the status of each portal.
With that, I'm able to plan  my journey and know what to do so that I can efficiently plan my operations in the game.

[image: Mind the big green field.]

With that said, is there any way I can do the same in Pokemon Go?
Obviously, not to take down portals, but to weave my daily commute to school to pass through as many PokeStops or Gyms (and Portals) as possible for the sake of resource gathering?

Edit: Mind the BAF (Big-As Field). Feel free to edit with an area without the Big-As Field.

Comment: I've been using some plugins [mentioned here](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4rm9rt/faq_here_is_how_niantic_knew_about_that_local/) that convert the Ingress Intel map to a map of PokeStops and Gyms.

Comment: @pushasha A quote from the Reddit post: "THE SERVERS FOR THIS ARE CURRENTLY PRETTY DAMN DEAD, AND THERE'S A BUG. JUST USE IITC ALONE FOR NOW". Also, I tried that; it kinda killed my browser or showed Ingress portals as there are "no" PokeStops in the area I'm looking at. I zoomed out and found a few, but those are about a hundred kilometers from my active operations area (AKA. In New South Whales)

Comment: While [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272865/is-there-a-way-to-see-the-pokestops-and-gyms-on-a-map?rq=1) question is a duplicate, the answer there is inconclusive of an official map. It simply tells you to use Ingress Portals as a guide.

Comment: I could be wrong about this, but I was under the impression that questions that are duplicates should still be marked as duplicates, even if the answers provided for the original question are not satisfactory.

Comment: @pushasha That is correct. That's why I went ahead and marked it as duplicate (thus it only have two people closing it). My vote as question asker counts as the community bot's vote.